# Existing Chat-Text Systems with Autocomplete?

Tags: teamwork

We're building a multiplayer (dyads) puzzle game where players need to collaborate to be successful. We'd like to use a text chat system that has two must have features: a) autocompletes a player's statements/questions and b) allows only a limited number of predefined messages to be sent.

Any advice on where to go looking for existing text/chat systems with at least the autocomplete feature?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If the messages are predefined why do you need autocomplete? Don't you just pick them somehow as a user?